# Closed form of $\sum_{k=0}^{N-3}\frac{1}{N-k-1}$ for $N\geq3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm interested in obtained a simplified version (or closed form solution, not sure of the correct terminology here) of the following sum:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{N-3}\frac{1}{N-k-1} \ \text{where} \ N\geq3.  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
\end{equation}

I've never studied anything like this before and initially thought I could use results such as the sum of sequence of squares; however, I sent the problem to my friend and he has suggested that this is a partial sum of the harmonic series so there is no closed form solution (i.e, it's not equal to some expression that doesn't include a summation).

My end goal is to compare (1) to

$$\frac{N-1}{N+1}. \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Any guidance is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Define a new index $n$ by $n := N-k-1$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N-3}\frac{1}{N-k-1}
= \sum_{n=N-1}^{2} \frac{1}{n}
= \sum_{n=2}^{N-1} \frac{1}{n}
= H_{N-1} - 1
$$
where $H_m$ denotes the $m$th harmonic number, $H_m := \sum_{k=1}^m \frac 1 k$.

Your friend is correct. There is no known meaningful closed form for these numbers, beyond representations by other special nonelementary functions or other numbers. More can be found on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) for the harmonic numbers.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Defining the new index makes that very clear.  Is there any way remaining to compare your harmonic representation of (1) to (2) in my post? On the Wiki I see that "The nth harmonic number is about as large as the natural logarithm of n." so I'm wondering if there is anything in that direction.

Comment: Using the asymptotic expansion mentioned in the Wiki $H_{N-1}\approx \ln(N-1)+\gamma+1/2(N-1)-1/12(N-1)^2$ gives the the desired result when I compare the expression to (2).  Hopefully this is correct!